# MediaLibrary.SavePicture saves the picture stream in reduced resolution

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, stream, cameracapturetask

I build an app that allows the user to capture an image and then save it to both the isolated storage and the phone's Media Library.

When I download these two pictures to my PC, I see that the one saved in isolated storage has a resolution of 2592x1944 pixels and 262 dpi, while the one saved in Media Library is 1222x1630 and 72 dpi. I cannot explain why this happens. My related code-behind is:

```
//Save image to isolated storage
Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

//Save image to Media Library
MediaLibrary medialibrary = new MediaLibrary();
medialibrary.SavePicture(imageName, e.ChosenPhoto;);
```

(wb is a WritableBitmap that is created from e.ChosenPhoto)

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it has something to do with saving it from the ChosenPhoto instead of from a WriteableBitmap. Try saving the picture to the media library [from Isolated Storage instead like this](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/encode-and-decode-images-in-wp7).

```
// Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
fileStream.Close();

// Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
fileStream = store.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
Picture pic = mediaLibrary.SavePicture("savedflimage.jpg", fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: I implemented this and what happens is that the image from Media Library is still 1222x1630 but the dpi is improved: 165 dpi. Weird, isn't it?